# Convert string to const char* issue

Tags: c++, string

```
string str1 = "hello";
    const char* string1 = str1;
```

I get an error..

> cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ in initialization

how do i cast string to const char*

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> how do i cast string to const char*?

use [std::string::c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function, it returns a **non-modifiable** standard C character array version of the string.

```
const char* string1 = str1.c_str();
```

Comment: Which is valid until the next call to a non-const member of `string` (or the destructor of the string object).

Comment: str1.data() is not guaranteed to be null terminated so I would be a bit careful of this.

Answer (score 2):

Try `const char* string1 = str1.c_str();`

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
string str1 = "hello";
const char* string1 = str1.c_str();
```